# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MKPlacemark' with an argument list of type

Tags: swift, locationmanager, mkplacemark

I used LocationManager which you can find on this gitHub https://github.com/varshylmobile/LocationManager/blob/master/LocationManager.swift
2 months ago with Swift 1.2 and it was working perfectly. I just converted my app in Swift 2.0, I solved all the problems but there is still this one that I don't find how to fix.

Here is the error : Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MKPlacemark' with an argument list of type '(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, addressDictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject])'

Someone has any idea how to solve it ?

Oscar

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWnCn.png

Comment: try casting as? [String : AnyObject] or just declare it as Swift native dictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary

Comment: @Oscar can you please share the full updated class to swift 2.0?

Comment: I have also use the above class from the same source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Leo Dabus, it works !

```
as? [String : AnyObject]
```